# sweetalert2: use as preloader of content

Tags: sweetalert, sweetalert2

I would like to use the sweetalert2 this way:

```
$('.preloaderContent').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swal({
            title: "Data collecting....",
            text: "Please Wait!",
            type: "info",
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            preConfirm: function() {
                return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "get",
                        url: '/reports/test',
                        success: function(response){
                            $('.page-content').html(response);
                        }
                    })
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

How can I use 'swal.clickConfirm()' to start the loading without the need of letting the user hit the 'OK' Button?

And how can I close the swal window after all content is loaded?

Thanks so much!

!!! UPDATE:

This way it is working for me:

```
$('.preloadData').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        swal({
            title: "Collecting data....",
            text: "Please wait just one moment",
            type: "info",
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            onOpen: function(){
                swal.clickConfirm();
            },
            preConfirm: function() {
                return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "get",
                        url: '/x/xx/',
                        success: function(response){
                            $('.page-content').html(response);
                            swal.closeModal();
                        }
                    })
                });
            },allowOutsideClick: false
        });
    });
```